# Función para modificar un campo en SQLAlchemy: le quiero pasar el nombre del campo y el nuevo valor

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Tengo un problema para usar exec (para nombrar al vuelo o de forma dinámica) junto con SQLAlchemy. He programado una función al que la paso el nombre del campo y el nuevo valor (campo y valor). El exec tendría que hacer la búsqueda de ese valor y cambiarlo. Si el contenido del exec lo muestro por un print parece que esta correcto. No se como solucionarlo.

Os lo paso:
Para la búsqueda:

```
exec(f"preferencia = session.query(Preferencia).filter(Preferencia.nombre == '{campo}').first()")
```

Y para actualizar el valor:

```
exec(f"preferencia.{campo} = '{valor}'")
```

El error que genera es este:

**session.add(preferencia)**
**NameError: name 'preferencia' is not defined**

Os paso lo que tengo:
En una función:

```
        if radioBtn.text() == 'Si':
            self.cambio_en_ORM('realizado_cursiva', 'True')
        if radioBtn.text() == 'No':
            self.cambio_en_ORM('realizado_cursiva', 'False')
```

Y la función en cuestión:

```
    def cambio_en_ORM(self, campo, valor):
       engine = create_engine(f"sqlite:///{RUTA}/Gestor de hábitos.db", echo=False)
       Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
       Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
       session = Session()
       print(f"campo: {campo}, valor: {valor}")
       #preferencia = session.query(Preferencia).filter(Preferencia.nombre == "'"+campo+"'").first()
       #print(f"preferencia = session.query(Preferencia).filter(Preferencia.nombre == '{campo}').first()")
       exec(f"preferencia = session.query(Preferencia).filter(Preferencia.nombre == '{campo}').first()")
       #print(f"preferencia.{campo} = '{valor}'")
       exec(f"preferencia.{campo} = '{valor}'")
       # preferencia.realizado_cursiva = valor
       session.add(preferencia)
       session.commit()
       print(preferencia)
```

¿alguna sugerencia?
¿otra forma de hacerlo?
Mil gracias,

Answer (score 0):

La solución es actualizar:

```
    def cambio_en_ORM(self, campo, valor):
    """Actualiza los valores de la bbdd de preferencias

    Args:
        campo (string): campo de la bbdd a cambiar
        valor (string): valor a cambiar
    """
    print('\n\n-Función: cambio_en_ORM')
    engine = create_engine(
        f"sqlite:///{RUTA}/Gestor de hábitos.db", echo=False)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()
    #print(f"    campo: {campo}, valor: {valor}")
    session.query(Preferencia).filter(Preferencia.nombre == campo).update(
        {
            Preferencia.valor: valor
        }
    )
    session.commit()
```